# Google Plus - Party Mode

Tags: google-plus

So I created an event for Xmas today and I set the start time for the midnight and then 5 minutes ahead of creation of the event.

But I haven't been given the option to enable party mode. And I have searched everywhere to enable it.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: From [this article - "How It Works"](http://www.scotduke.com/2013/02/11/google-mobile-app-party-mode/): *Once someone confirms they are going to a G+ Event, the Party Mode becomes available on that person’s smartphone immediately when the the Event is scheduled to start*. So I guess, it will be done automatically, and the event creator doesn't need to do anything. That's what I understand (but never tried, so I don't know)

Comment: So I have taken a few photos and so have other people since the event started. And none of the photos have uploaded to the event.

Comment: from the looks of it this awesome feature has been removed